# One or more multiply defined symbols found Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I got this error, which I don't get at all. I interpreted it to be that I have something that's defined differently more than once, but when I look through my code, I just don't see it. I uploaded the codes that the error message has pointed to:

```
 teamdata.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall teamdata::getTeamnumber(void)" (?getTeamnumber@teamdata@@QAEHXZ) already defined in scouting.obj
 teamdata.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall teamdata::operator<(class teamdata)" (??Mteamdata@@QAE_NV0@@Z) already defined in scouting.obj
 release\Scouting.exe:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Links:
teamdata.h        http://pastebin.com/5u0YzK84

teamdata.cpp        http://pastebin.com/GP0zRzpw

Comment: main code <http://pastebin.com/aH8Auy4c>

Comment: Do you have a scouting.cpp file that either provides or used to provide parts of the teamdata class?

Comment: Put your code in the question, not on pastebin. StackOverflow is not a forum and typical forum rules do not apply. You can edit your question to do this.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Also, how do I paste long strings of code without the whole 4 space indentation thing. I dont want to indent every single line of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the linker is telling you, your functions `getTeamnumber()` and `operator <` are *defined* in **two** different translation units: in `scouting.cpp` (I guess that's the name of the file) and in `teamdata.cpp`.

It does not matter whether the definitions are identical or different (function templates are an exception to this rule, but that's not your case, as your functions are not tmeplates), as long as they are *multiple*.

The **One Definition Rule** (Clause 3 of the C++ Standard) states that each entity of your program shall only have one definition.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I derped so hard. I forgot to delete the that small string of code after I copied and moved it to teamdata.cpp. So sorry

Comment: @Lawlhwut: No worries, we've all been there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the standard answer that the linker is right...

I am not sure about your project is configured or how you code is laid out...so take this with a grain of salt.

Move your definition for those to methods out of the class header file to the class definition file...

Comment: The definitions are not in the class header file, only the declarations  are. That's correct. What is incorrect is that he defines those functions in two separate cpp files.

Comment: If you can't even check the code I think you should have posted this as a comment rather than an answer :-)